# Why LoginResponse is not called in filamentphp 3 multi tenancy app?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

In laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 app with multi tenancy I want to redirect to custom page on login.
Depending on access of logged user I need to redirect to specific page.

I found docs how to make it at https://laraveldaily.com/post/filament-disable-dashboard-auto-redirect-url-after-login

But class in app/Http/Responses/LoginResponse.php :

```
namespace App\Http\Responses;

use App\Filament\App\Resources\EmployeeResource;
use App\Filament\App\Resources\UserQuizRequestResource;
use Filament\Facades\Filament;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Livewire\Features\SupportRedirects\Redirector;

class LoginResponse extends \Filament\Http\Responses\Auth\LoginResponse
{
    public function toResponse($request): RedirectResponse|Redirector
    {
        halt("app/Http/Responses/LoginResponse.php");

        is not called at all, with definition in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php :

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(
            LoginResponse::class,
            \App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse::class // TODO
        );
```

I have 2 panels defined app/Providers/Filament/AdminPanelProvider.php:

```
namespace App\Providers\Filament;    
use Awcodes\FilamentQuickCreate\QuickCreatePlugin;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DisableBladeIconComponents;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DispatchServingFilamentEvent;
use Filament\Navigation\MenuItem;
use Filament\Support\Colors\Color;
use Jeffgreco13\FilamentBreezy\BreezyCore;
use Filament\Panel;
use Filament\PanelProvider;
use Filament\Widgets;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;
use pxlrbt\FilamentEnvironmentIndicator\EnvironmentIndicatorPlugin;
use pxlrbt\FilamentSpotlight\SpotlightPlugin;
use App\Http\Middleware\VerifyIsBranchActive;
use App\Http\Middleware\VerifyIsAdmin;
use Saade\FilamentFullCalendar\FilamentFullCalendarPlugin;

class AdminPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    {
        return $panel
            ->authGuard('web')
            ->plugins([
                ...
            ])
            ->font('DejaVu Sans')
            ->id('admin')
            ->path('admin')
            ->userMenuItems([
                MenuItem::make()
                    ->label('Go To App')
                    ->icon('heroicon-o-cog-6-tooth')
                    ->url('/app'),
            ])
            ->discoverResources(in: app_path('Filament/Resources'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Resources')
            ->discoverPages(in: app_path('Filament/Pages'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Pages')
            ->pages([
                \App\Filament\Pages\AdminDashboard::class,
            ])
            ->discoverWidgets(in: app_path('Filament/Widgets'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Widgets')
            ->databaseNotifications()
            ->middleware([
                EncryptCookies::class,
                AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                StartSession::class,
                AuthenticateSession::class,
                ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                SubstituteBindings::class,
                DisableBladeIconComponents::class,
                DispatchServingFilamentEvent::class,
                VerifyIsAdmin::class,
                VerifyIsBranchActive::class,
            ])

            ->tenantMiddleware([
                \Hasnayeen\Themes\Http\Middleware\SetTheme::class
            ]);
    }
}
```

and in app/Providers/Filament/AppPanelProvider.php :

```
namespace App\Providers\Filament;

use App\Filament\App\Pages\Auth\Register;
use App\Filament\App\Pages\Tenancy\EditBranchProfile;
use App\Filament\App\Pages\Tenancy\RegisterBranch;
use App\Http\Middleware\VerifyIsBranchActive;
use App\Http\Middleware\VerifyIsManager;
use App\Library\AppLocale;
use App\Models\Branch;
use Jeffgreco13\FilamentBreezy\BreezyCore;
use Awcodes\FilamentQuickCreate\QuickCreatePlugin;
use Filament\Facades\Filament;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DisableBladeIconComponents;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DispatchServingFilamentEvent;
use Filament\Navigation\MenuItem;
use Filament\Pages;
use Filament\Panel;
use Filament\PanelProvider;
use Filament\Support\Colors\Color;
use Filament\Widgets;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;
use App\Livewire\CustomProfileComponent;
use pxlrbt\FilamentEnvironmentIndicator\EnvironmentIndicatorPlugin;
use Saade\FilamentFullCalendar\FilamentFullCalendarPlugin;

class AppPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    {
        return $panel
            ->default()
            ->authGuard('web')
            ->plugins([
                ...
            ])
            ->id('app')
            ->path('app')
            ->login()
            ->registration(Register::class)
            ->userMenuItems([
                MenuItem::make()
                    ->label('Go To Admin')
                    ->icon('heroicon-o-cog-6-tooth')
                    ->url('/admin')
                    ->visible(fn(): bool => auth()->user() ?           auth()->user()->isAdmin(): false),
            ])

            ->discoverResources(in: app_path('Filament/App/Resources'), for: 'App\\Filament\\App\\Resources')
            ->discoverPages(in: app_path('Filament/App/Pages'), for: 'App\\Filament\\App\\Pages')
            ->pages([
                Pages\Dashboard::class,
            ])
            ->discoverWidgets(in: app_path('Filament/App/Widgets'), for: 'App\\Filament\\App\\Widgets')
            ->widgets([
                Widgets\AccountWidget::class,
                Widgets\FilamentInfoWidget::class,
            ])
            ->middleware([
                EncryptCookies::class,
                AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                StartSession::class,
                AuthenticateSession::class,
                ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                SubstituteBindings::class,
                DisableBladeIconComponents::class,
                DispatchServingFilamentEvent::class,
                VerifyIsBranchActive::class,
                VerifyIsManager::class,
            ])
            ->databaseNotifications()
            ->authMiddleware([
                Authenticate::class,
            ])

            ->tenantMiddleware([
                \Hasnayeen\Themes\Http\Middleware\SetTheme::class
            ])
            ->viteTheme('resources/css/filament/app/theme.css')
            ->tenant(Branch::class, ownershipRelationship: 'branch', slugAttribute: 'slug')
            ->tenantRegistration(RegisterBranch::class)
            ->tenantProfile(EditBranchProfile::class);
    }
}
```

So I moved default, login and registration methods under app.
I remade registration with additive fields.

But why LoginResponse is not called after login and how to fix it ?